# Convert image to N grays + transparency

Tags: php, image

I've been trying all sorts of combinations of image functions, but I just can't seem to get a good result for this.

I'm trying to convert images into a fixed number of levels of grey, plus transparency (if it exists in the original image).

It needs to be able to convert both true-color images and palette-based images.

The output image should have...

1. A fixed number of levels of gray, including pure black (0, 0, 0) and pure white (255, 255, 255).
2. Transparent pixels anywhere that the source pixel has a high level of transparency.

My main problem is with the working of imagetruecolortopalette, which does reduce the palette but always seems to lose any transparency in the process.

I ended up writing a very long, complex piece of code that analysed the image pixel-by-pixel for gray levels, then choose palette colors, then recreated the image pixel-by-pixel, but it's pretty slow, so I'm hoping there's a better way.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do something like this about a year ago. However the task was a little simpler since I converted the image to black or white only.

- The algorithm created a new image with the same size as the old one.
- Then it looked at each pixel of the old one and calculated its luminance by a weighted sum:
  0.2 R + 0.7 G + 0.1 B = brightness
- The brightness was then used to determine the color.
- And the new color was written to the corresponding pixel of the second image

The images that I used had no transparency but I guess you could just copy the transparency value to the new image. I don't understand how you lose the transparency information. Couldn't you just read and write the alpha channel ?

Back then I implemented this in python and it ran very fast. Processing 1.000.000 pixels took a fraction of seconds. Therefore I would guess that your performance problems are connected to php rather than the task itself. Moreover I don't think there's much room for optimisations. After all you either have to look at all the pixels or you would lose image resolution. The processing itself is rather straightforward.

Comment: There's definitely some performance issues in PHP in doing pixel-by-pixel updates, so it's preferable to use the in-built image functions where possible.  I've since simplified my method, and have improved the performance, but I'd still like to know if it can be done just using image functions rather than this brute-force pixel-by-pixel approach.